# array.get() out of bounds error but ternary statement checks to ensure enough data exists beforehand

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

trying to use the request.security_lower_tf function to collect the M1 high data for the previous M5 candle i.e. not the current M5 candle but the one that just closed ... [1]

However I'm getting this error in the chart window. 'In array.get() function Index 1 is out of bounds, array size is 1'.

Two questions really, is my syntax for requesting the M1 data for the previously closed M5 bar correct? Why am I getting this error when the ternary statements check that the array size is large enough to ask for the data at the specific index.

Any insight appreciated. Thanks. Adam.

```
// Get lower timeframe data
float[] M1LtfHigh_Array = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "1" , high)

// Create variables to hold M1 data
float m1c0High = 0.0
float m1c1High = 0.0
float m1c2High = 0.0
float m1c3High = 0.0
float m1c4High = 0.0

// This ensures there is at least one candle in history before the below variables are set to avoid errors
if(bar_index >= 1)      

// Get M1 High data for last M5 candle. To me [1] is lookback of the M5 candle I am interested in. The other 0,1,2,3,4 are the index of the M1 highs array.
    m1c0High := array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array[1],0)      // This line doesn't cause the error
    m1c1High := array.size(M1LtfHigh_Array) >=2 ? array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array[1],1) : 0.0      // From here the error occurs
    m1c2High := array.size(M1LtfHigh_Array) >=3 ? array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array[1],2) : 0.0
    m1c3High := array.size(M1LtfHigh_Array) >=4 ? array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array[1],3) : 0.0
    m1c4High := array.size(M1LtfHigh_Array) >=5 ? array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array[1],4) : 0.0

//Populate table with values
var table minDataTable = table.new(position.bottom_right,5,1)
if barstate.islast and not m1c0High == 0.0
    table.cell(minDataTable, 0, 0, text = "HIGH", text_color = color.white, bgcolor=color.gray)
    table.cell(minDataTable, 1, 0, str.tostring(m1c0High), text_color = color.white, bgcolor=color.gray)
    table.cell(minDataTable, 2, 0, str.tostring(m1c1High), text_color = color.white, bgcolor=color.gray)
```

Can't find any specific documentation on the syntax for using the array.get function on arrays for candles other than the current candle[0]. So I've tried changing up the syntax in a few different configs to see if that helps but it doesn't.

E.g.
m1c1High := array.size(M1LtfHigh_Array) >=2 ? array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array[1],1) : 0.0
m1c1High := array.size(M1LtfHigh_Array) >=2 ? array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array,1[1]) : 0.0
m1c1High := array.size(M1LtfHigh_Array) >=2 ? array.get(M1LtfHigh_Array,1)[1] : 0.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that first line which you commented as "This line doesn't cause the error" will definitely cause an error. So, you should add a size check there too.

Your main problem is; you are checking the size of `M1LtfHigh_Array` but trying to access `M1LtfHigh_Array[1]`. `M1LtfHigh_Array[1]` will have the historical values and therefore its size won't match with `M1LtfHigh_Array`.

Either check the size of `M1LtfHigh_Array[1]` or use `array.get()` on `M1LtfHigh_Array`.